# Office Add-in platform compability

Tags: outlook, ms-office, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

### Issue

I'm trying to help a customer of ours to install our addin on their Exchange 2013. When they try to add our add-in through EAC it says:

[image: The API version (1.3) required by this app isn't supported by the Exchange Server version (15.0.1236.3) that you're connecting to]

> The API version (1.3) required by this app isn't supported by the
>   Exchange Server version (15.0.1236.3) that you're connecting to

### What I've tried

The version number indicates that they are using Exchange Server 2013 CU14.

I've dug through loads and loads of documentation to try to find version of Exchange they need in order to install it. It says in some places that they need Exchange 2013 or later to run addins - which they have.

### Questions

1. What version of exchange is required to run API version 1.3?
2. What's the easiest way for them to upgrade to that version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API version 1.3 is supported by Exchange 2016.

Comment: Okay. Thank you! What is the best way for them to have our add-in work? If they can't upgrade their exchange? What about if they allow their users to install addins themselves?

Comment: According to https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/tutorial-api-requirement-sets Outlook 2013 on Windows should support Mailbox 1.4. Why does the Exchange version interfere with what addins are compatible with Outlook?

Comment: The manifest for an Outlook Web Add-ins isn't installed on the client, they're installed in the user's Exchange Mailbox. 
In order to Outlook Web Add-ins to work, they need to interact with APIs on both the client and the server. Some activities are purely client-side (i.e. inserting text while composing a message), other activities require interacting with EWS on the backend (i.e. setting and retrieving roaming settings).
This question is also currently being addressed here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/issues/1371.